# Commerce rule for total of product lines only (not shipping as well)

Tags: commerce, workflows

I have a requirement to add an amount to the total of all Commerce product lines items in a users cart and then add that amount to the shipping amount.

The rule I currently have uses the "**calculating a shipping rate**" event. The element on the rule uses "**Calculate a value**" with the input value as **commerce-line-item:order:commerce-order-total:amount**. However, this value also takes into account the shipping. I only want to apply the calculation to the ordered items in the cart - not shipping as well.

Does anyone know how I can access just the **sub**total for the cart?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Using `[site:current-cart-order:commerce-order-total:amount]` seems to do the trick.

Comment: You're encouraged to [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) on Drupal Answers. If this is how you solved the problem, mark it as the accepted answer for future user.